# Find duplicate elements based on another tag value XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an extremely complicated XML and I need to check if a particular element exists only once inside each child of the XML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deal>
   <commercial>
      <party />
      <party>
         <role_detail>
            <role_type>Primary</role_type>
         </role_detail>
         <listingagents>
            <listingagent>1</listingagent>
            <listingagent>2</listingagent>
         </listingagents>
      </party>
      <party>
         <role_detail>
            <role_type>Secondary</role_type>
         </role_detail>
         <listingagents>
            <listingagent>1</listingagent>
         </listingagents>
      </party>
      <party />
   </commercial>
   <commercial />
   <commercial />
</deal>
```

Each commercial tag should contain only one listingagent tag when the party tag has role_type = PRIMARY.

For each commercial, I need to pick out party of type Primary and then check for listingagents tag and it should contain only one child listingagent.

Comment: a series of xpaths could do the trick. have you tried anything ?

Comment: What are the requirements when the party *doesn't* have a role type of PRIMARY? And it looks like it's the listingAgent within the *party* tag, not within the *commercial* tag. (It would also help if you'd indent the XML for the sake of readability.)

Comment: It will have a Primary role type. Yes listingagent is within Party. But I need to perform this check on the entire xml for each Commercial tag. I need to do this with LINQ

Answer (score 0):

Use XML Schema.xsd and limit your occurs:

For instance:

```
<xs:element name="listingagents" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="listingagentsType"/>

 <xs:complexType name="listingagentsType">
   <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="listingagent" type="parameterType" maxOccurs="1"/>
   </xs:sequence>
```

Comment: But it can occur more than once in the entire file. It should occur once for each primary role type

Comment: listingagent will occur 0 or 1 times every time it will be nested in listingagents. You can set minOccurs as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement xml = //...
bool xmlIsInvalid = xml.Elements("commercial")
    .Select(c => c.Elements("party")
    .Single(p => p.Element("role_detail").Element("role_type").Value == "Primary"))
    .Any(p => p.Element("listingagents").Elements("listingagent").Count() > 1);
```

For every `commercial` element, get the single child `party` element whose `role_type` is `Primary`. Return true if any of these `party` elements contain more than 1 `listingagent`in `listingagents`.

Note this solution assumes a number of things about the structure of your XML - i.e. `party` will always have a child `role_detail` element, `listingagents` will always have at least one `listingagent`, etc.

Comment: will this work if there are multiple commercial tags?

Comment: Yes, it processes every commercial tag and will set `xmlIsInValid` to true if any of them do not meet the criteria.

Comment: Hey Can't I use .Single(p => p.Element"role_type").Value == "Primary")) in the 4th line??

Comment: `Element` returns the direct descendant - so as `role_type` is not a direct descendant of `party`, that would not work - you could use `Descendants("role_type").Single()` instead though, as this returns any matching descendants.

Comment: That's scary.. this was just a sample xml i created.. in reality none of these are direct descendents, What should I do?

Comment: `Descendants` _should_ work, but as I have no idea of the true structure of your XML, I'm now only guessing.

Comment: Can you share the revised code? using `descendants`?

Comment: How to handle if only one of the party tag will contain role_type element?

Comment: Can you update your question with a more representative example and clear specifications?

Answer (score 0):

I like querying XML nodes with XDocument (System.Xml.Linq). I would first find the invalid primary parties with more than 1 listing agent, and go from there...

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText("XMLFile1.xml"));
var allParties = doc.Descendants("commercial").Elements("party");

// invalid primary parties with more than 1 listing agent
var invalidPrimaries = allParties.Where(p => p.Element("role_detail")?.Value.ToUpper() == "PRIMARY" && 
                                             p.Element("listingagents")?.Elements("listingagent").Count() > 1);

var validParties = allParties.Except(invalidPrimaries);
var validCommericals = validParties.Select(p => p.Parent).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Hi what if role_detail is not a direct child of Party?

Comment: Note the use of the `?.` null conditional operator to only continue evaluating if it's not null (the _party_ tag has a _role_detail_ child) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx